# How to properly read to stop words with Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I can't figure out how to read text with parsec to a stop word, I understand that you can do something like this

```
paramBlockExpr :: Parser ParamBlock
paramBlockExpr = do
  p <- paramExpr
  txt <- many1 anyChar 
  _ <- string "stop_word"
  return $ ParamBlock p txt
```

But then parsec will move the carriage and stop_word is no longer readable, I read something about `lookAHead`, but I do not understand if it is applicable here

P.S

By the way the example will not work either, `anyChar` will absorb stop_word

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
absorbToStopWord :: Parser String
absorbToStopWord = try ("" <$ string "stop_word")
               <|> liftA2 (:) anyChar absorbToStopWord
```

Comment: this function reads the forbidden word

Answer (score 0):

I took Daniel Wagner's feature (thanks to him for that) and tweaked it a bit, so now it looks like this:

```
absorbToStopWordNoRead :: String -> Parser String
absorbToStopWordNoRead stopWord = lookAhead ("" <$ string stopWord)
                       <|> liftA2 (:) anyChar (absorbToStopWordNoRead stopWord)
```